# http static handler resource base path

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have a html file under `src/main/resources` in mule project. How to mention the relative path for html file with respect to my project directory in resource base path field for http static resource handler to render the html file. I have given `${app.home}/src/main/resources` in resource base but `${app.home}` is pointing to a directory like below

> /Users/xx/git/projects/**.mule/apps**/integration/src/main/resources/

I am not sure why its looking under .mule/apps directory.

My html file is under this path.

> /Users/xx/git/projects/integration/src/main/resources/app.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ${app.home} points to right place. Don't forget that you run application which is archived(zipped), deployed and ran on the application server which is not your environment in Anypoint Studio.

So, when it runs it runs in another place. You should have all necessary files in this new place. To make it easy - use resources not files. Let application server carry where files are.

Here is simple example which shows any static file (as resource) from directory **public** 
[image]

Here is code

```
<flow name="publicFilesHttpsFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTPS_listner" path="/StatusESB/public/*" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <set-variable variableName="resourceName" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.request.uri'].substring(18)]" doc:name="Variable"/>

        <set-payload value="#[Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(flowVars.resourceName)]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        </flow>
```

In this example any file under directory src/main/resources/public which is resource and delvered via deplyment to the application server will be visible as html page. Like

https://localhost/StatusESB/public/HelloWorld.html

Comment: is this achievable using http static handler?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "http static handler". Assuming you mean writing individual http listener for each individual file like separate listeners for requests like /HelloWorld.html, /HelloWorld1.html, /HelloWorld2.html - yes it could be done. That would be great cause to hire army of developers ;)

Comment: What i meant was something like this                                          <http:static-resource-handler resourceBase="/Users/xx/git/projects/integration/src/main/resources/app.html" defaultFile="app.html" doc:name="HTTP Static Resource Handler"/>

Comment: I meant the same. In this case you need one for each file. In my example you need one for all files.